# Loading gmaps4rails into custom formtastic field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic, gmaps4rails

I am trying to find a way to load gmaps4rails map into a custom formtastic field (to be used in Active Admin)

I have this:

```
class GmapInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def to_html
    gmaps4rails(Location.new)
  end
end
```

which is firing, but I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `gmaps4rails' for #<GmapInput:0x007f9cae5b2780>
```

I assume this is because gmaps4rails isn't loaded yet. How can I ensure it gets loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm, never used formtastic but...

I guess the issue stems from the fact `gmaps4rails` is a helper and your class doesn't have access to it.

In standard form builder you simply have to do delegate helper's calls to `@template` ( so `@template.gmaps4rails` ).

BTW, there is an other weird thing: why do you pass `Location.new` to `gmaps4rails`? It couldn't do much with such an object: it expects json.